# ng-options loop through an array of objects within an object?

Tags: javascript, html, ng-options

I have this object format

```
{
      first_name : "Bob",
      last_name : "Smith",
      addresses : [
        {address:"1 Baker Street",
          city: "london"
        },
        {address:"2 Baker Street",
          city: "london"
        }
        ]
    }
```

I want to set the address bits in the select dropdown i.e. "1 Baker Street", "2 Baker Street",

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedAddress" ng-options="item for item in testObject">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testObject =     {
          first_name : "Bob",
          last_name : "Smith",
          addresses : [
            {address:"1 Baker Street",
              city: "london"
            },
            {address:"2 Baker Street",
              city: "london"
            }
            ]
        }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm struggling to get my head around how to loop through the objects with AngularJS. Any help?

Comment: your missing the testObject.addresses on html binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call the child object of array and the property. Take a look this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testObject =     {
          first_name : "Bob",
          last_name : "Smith",
          addresses : [
            {address:"1 Baker Street",
              city: "london"
            },
            {address:"2 Baker Street",
              city: "london"
            }
            ]
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedAddress" ng-options="item.address for item in testObject.addresses">
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem" 
         ng-options="selectedItem as selectedItem.address       
                     for selectedItem in testObject.addresses">  
</select>
```

You can also set default `selectedItem` as 1st item in list

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.testObject.addresses[0];
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qam5qdg6/)</kbd>