# angularJS select is not initialized when using object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am using the following in my HTML

```html
<select class="form-control"
                        required
                        ng-model="crud.model.dateRange"                       
                        ng-options="range as range.description for range in crud.metaData.dateRanges"></select>
```

I added tt debug to see that I do have a proper crud.model.dateRange object. However, my form doesn't show the select properly initialized with my object info.

I have a vague recollection I had a similar problem before. Do you know how to make my form show the info properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370479/ng-options-loop-through-an-array-of-objects-within-an-object Check this link

Comment: I checked this and I was also reading several other answers with ng-options tag, but nothing as yet helpful. May be I need to try to set initial value for crud.model.dateRange in my controller's code to be from the array? (And not even return it originally);

Comment: can you share your data model?

Comment: I gave up (for now) and changed from object to just Id. This worked.
E.g. I used range.id in ng-options. And changed my model to use Id instead of object too.